# How do I write events and eventhandlers in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, events

I've been trying a good way to memorize how to write events and eventhandlers in C# for a while. Whenever I want to refer to a tutorial on the Internet they tend to be verbose.

The question is how do I write events and eventhandlers in C#? Have you got a code example that illustrates easily how to write such?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They don't have to be verbose:

```
// declare an event:
public event EventHandler MyEvent;

// raise an event:
var handler = MyEvent;
if(handler != null) handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);

// consume an event with an anon-method:
obj.MyEvent += delegate { Console.WriteLine("something happened"); };

// consume an event with a named method:
obj.MyEvent += SomeHandler;

void SomeHandler(object sender, EventArgs args) {
    Console.WriteLine("something happened");
}
```

What is the bit that is being troublesome?

Comment: +1. I knew either you or Jon would beat me to this one... and give a better answer

Comment: the bit that is being troublesome are all tutorials that tend to describe delegates as well but all I want is a quick reference

Comment: I laughed at the "something happened" message! THE famous Windows 10 setup error message :)

Answer (score 1):

Once you get an appetite, try this out:

For VS2005:
How to: Publish Events that Conform to .NET Framework Guidelines (C# Programming Guide)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w369ty8x(v=vs.80).aspx

For Visual Studio 11:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w369ty8x(v=vs.110).aspx